# How to find a char in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, nested-lists

I'm writing code that creates a crossword and I want code that finds a specific char in a table.
so for example if the board contains the word 'car' and I'm looking for the char 'a', it would return the value for the row and column.
This is the code I have for printing the board and the first word.

```
board = [[' '] * 20 for i in range(20)] 
def printboard(board):
    columns = '01234567890123456789'
    rows = '_' * 20
    print(' ' + columns)
    print(' ' + rows)
    for i in range(20):
        s = ''.join(board[i])
        print('|' + s +'|' + str(i))
    print(' ' + rows)
    print(' ' + columns)

def addFirstWord(board, word):
    n = len(word)
    if n > 20:
        return False
    row = 10
    col = (20 - n) // 2
    board[row][col:col+n] = word
    return True
addFirstWord(board, 'car')
printboard(board)
```

I think I have to write a loop that checks every index in the board but i'm not sure how to write it. Thanks

Comment: As a side-note, it might be better to work with matrices instead of lists of lists. Should be simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
def findCharacter(board, char):
    # Loop through all rows and columns
    for i, c in enumerate(board):
        for j, r in enumerate(c):
            # If we find the character, return it
            if r == char:
                return j, i
```

For example:

```
>>> board = [[' '] * 20 for i in range(20)] 
>>> addFirstWord(board, 'car')
>>> findCharacter(board, 'c')
(8, 10)
```